# Linux: page-up key to browse through history

Tags: linux, bash, history

In some linux systems, when I write the beginning characters of a command and press page-up, I can browse through the latest similar commands saved in the history file. However, I found that this browsing by page-up key doesn't work on one ubuntu machine, so I want to add this capability to the system for convenience.

I did a little search, and found that ading these two lines to my .bashrc file will fix the problem:

```
bindkey -k up history-search-backward
bindkey -k down history-search-forward
```

but it didn't work, and in fact, it says

```
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
```

Any idea how to solve this issue on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `bash` and not `zsh` try putting the following in your `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist, so I created one! But still it doesn't work!

Comment: Ah, looks like I gave you the keys for up/down arrows. Edited to be page up/down.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in .bashrc file

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
bind '"\eOA": history-search-backward'
bind '"\eOB": history-search-forward'
```

and run the following command to activate

```
source ~/.bashrc
```